# How to get flat observable list from 2 level down keyed list in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I can't figure out how to get flat collection of Products where I've managed my data in form Prods/$companyKeys/$prodKeys

```
{
  "ID1" : {
    "prodID1" : {
      "name" : "Car"
    },
    "prodID2" : {
      "name" : "Door"
    },
    "prodID3" : {
      "name" : "Sandwich"
    }
  },
  "ID2" : {
    "ProdID4" : {
      "name" : "Glass"
    },
    "ProdID5" : {
      "name" : "Pen"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way in rxjs or in AngularFire2 itself to get directly collection of products, omitting company Ids? Or do I have to re-arrange my data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.flatMap` is made for such a purpose ([***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/zo0u04rf/)):

```
// turn products into array
var arr = [];
for(var key in products) {
  arr.push(products[key]);
}

Rx.Observable.from(arr)
  .flatMap(x => {
    // 'x' is like object ID1, create array of products
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in x) {
      arr.push(x[key]);
    }
    return Rx.Observable.from(arr);
  })
  .subscribe(x => document.write(JSON.stringify(x) + '</br>'));
```

Output:

```
{"name":"Car"}
{"name":"Door"}
{"name":"Glass"}
{"name":"Sandwich"}
{"name":"Pen"}
```

Not sure how you want to handle the keys, but you can use `Observable.pairs` to make it even easier to loop through the object properties.  The resulting stream is of arrays with the first element being the key and the second being the value for the object properties:

```
Rx.Observable.pairs(products)
    .flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.pairs(x[1]))
    .subscribe( x => console.log(x[0], x[1]));
```

This returns arrays like this:

```
["prodID1", {name: "Car"}]
["prodID2", {name: "Door"}]
["prodID3", {name: "Glass"}]
["prodID4", {name: "Sandwich"}]
["prodID5", {name: "Pen"}]
```

Comment: First output seems more like what I need. FirebaseListObservables (and ObjectObservable) have some extra properties such as key property, which I need to preserve in created observable list. I've changed my data structure, your answer pushed me to right direction in another problem though. Thanks